# Execute query without reload page with trigger in php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have data like this

```
This is the data in the table :
id | parent_id | name   |
---+-----------+--------|
  1|       NULL|    ROOT|
  2|          1| Item 1 |
  3|          1| Item 2 |
  4|          1| Item 3 |
  5|          1| Item 4 |
  6|          2| Item 5 |
  7|          2| Item 6 |
  8|          3| Item 7 |
```

and then my sql statement like this

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'my_db');
$id = 1;
$result = $conn->query("SELECT a.id, a.parent_id, a.name FROM table_name a where a.parent_id = $id");
```

and if I execute, the data will show like this

```
id | parent_id | name   |
---+-----------+--------|
  2|          1| Item 1 |
  3|          1| Item 2 |
  4|          1| Item 3 |
  5|          1| Item 4 |
```

Then, i show the data as a button with button label is "data['name']"

```
<?php
foreach($result as $row) { ?>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm" onclick="showID('<?= $row['id'] ?>')">
        <?= $row['name'] ?>
    </button>
<?php
    } 
?>
```

How can, if I click specific data, then the data will be changed based on the data that I clicked.

Which is if I click specific data the variable $id will change based on the id of the data that I clicked, like a tree.

For example,
Based on the query, the data that shown is  
    Item 1
    Item 2
 
    Item 3
    Item 4
because they have parent_id = 1
Then if i click or select "Item 2" the data that shown should be
 
Item 5
Item 6
because they have parent_id is = 2 based on id of their parent.

How to do that without reloading the page?
Thanks

Comment: Use ajax call on the button click so you can get the data.

Comment: If you want to change data without reloading the page, you should use Ajax : 1) add some onclick event on your button and send the id user click to the same php script you used before to display your data - 2) With the new id your script will return what you want - 3) In your Ajax success / done part update the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your javascript file you can done this through ajax.

```
function showID(id){
   $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
        url: 'function.php',
        data: {'id' : id},
        success: function (result) {
            $('#tblbody').html(result);
        }
})
}
```

and you have to return HTML with a given result. and the "#tblbody" is your tbody id